# Azure Cloud Service in Azure Virtual network

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vpn, azure

Can any one please help me to know the answers for the below points -> once After adding the web role in to azure virtual network?

1. Join Webroles to the Azure Virtual Network? (answer: yes)
2. Join Azure Virtual Network to VPN for on-premises connectivity
3. Join WebRoles to on premises Domain
4. Configure IIS in WebRoles to use Windows Authentication

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should use the VM Azure.

if you use VM:

1. yes.
2. yes, create Network, define address space that will not collide with the on premises, create VM, make sure VM connected to the network that you define, using Site to Site VPN for VPN to your premises.
3. yes.
4. yes, go to the VM and configure the IIS.